# Is my atom editor working correctly for R?

Tags: r, atom-editor

I'm new to using text editors for coding. I installed ide-r, atom-language-r in atom and the languageserver package in R as required by ide-r. However, I'm not sure if they are working correctly, for instance there doesn't seem be any difference whether I disable or enable ide-r, also when I type in 'print' it would be autocompleted to 'plot'. Is there something wrong?

Comment: You probably already know this, but you can use R-Studio and/or R-Studio Server. The R programmers I know tell me that's pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you have mentioned, the steps you have followed are correct for starting the R language in the Atom Editor. R must be started in your Atom Editor. For further queries, you can go through the following link.
[IDE-R package in Atom Editor](https://atom.io/packages/ide-r)